# what does it mean to ''apply linearity'' in differentiation and integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, terminology

In integration,

let's say I want to integrate $2(x+5)$

I could then put the $2$ in front of the integral sign and integrate $x+5$,
only to multiply it again by $2$ later. is this called ''applying linearity''?

And for differentiation,

let's say I want to differentiate

$2(x+5)$

could i then differentiate $x+5 = 1$
and then multiply my answer by $2 $

Is this called ''applying linearity''?

Could you give me the definition of the phrase ''apply linearity''?

Comment: A thing is linear if it acts like $D(f+g) = D(f) + D(g)$ and $D(cf)=cD(f)$ for $c$ constant.  Differentiation acts like this.

Comment: @Randall coud you explain in more details. leave an answer maybe?

Comment: See the two properties listed under [§"In mathematics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics)

Comment: thanks @user170231. what is homogeneity though?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Randall's comment: in your example, "applying linearity" means
\begin{align}
\int 2(x+5)dx & = \int (2x + 10) dx = \int 2xdx + \int 10 dx,\\
\frac{d}{dx} 2(x+5) & = \frac{d}{dx} (2x + 10) = \frac{d}{dx} (2x) + \frac{d}{dx} 10.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

### Expressing operations on functions with the language of linear algebra.

Let $\mathscr D$ and $\mathscr I$ denote the sets of differentiable and integrable functions from some closed interval $[a,b]\subset \Bbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Each of these sets are [*vector spaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) over $\mathbb R$ under the operations of pointwise addition $+$ and scalar multiplication $\cdot$, where, letting $u,v$ be functions and $c$ be a real number, these operations are defined by
$$(u+v)(x)=u(x)+v(x) \\ (c\cdot u)(x)=c~u(x)$$

If $(V,+,\cdot)$ and $(W,\oplus,\odot)$ are both vector spaces over the field $F$, a mapping $T:V\to W$ is *linear* if it preserves scalar multiplication and vector addition. That is letting $v_1,v_2\in V$ and $c\in F$,
$$T(v_1+v_2)=T(v_1)\oplus T(v_2) \\ T(c\cdot v_1)=c\odot T(v_1)$$
What linearity means in the context of integration and differentiation is that if we take the vector spaces $(\mathscr D,+,\cdot)$ and $(\mathscr I,+,\cdot)$ and introduce the derivative mapping
$$\mathrm D:\mathscr D\to\mathscr I \\ (\mathrm Df)(x):=\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$$
As well as the integral mapping
$$\mathrm I:\mathscr I\to\mathscr D \\ (\mathrm If)(x):=\int_a^x f(s)\mathrm ds$$

That both of these maps are **linear**, that is letting $f,g\in\mathscr D$ and $\phi,\psi\in\mathscr I$ and $c,d\in\mathbb R$, that
$$\mathrm D(c\cdot f+d\cdot g)=c\cdot\mathrm Df+d\cdot \mathrm Dg \\ \mathrm I(c\cdot \phi+d\cdot \psi)=c\cdot \mathrm I\phi+d\cdot \mathrm I\psi$$

So, why is this useful? Let's suppose for example we have our sine and cosine functions, and we did a lot of hard work using the limit definition of the derivative to show that
$$\mathrm D(\sin)=\cos \\ \mathrm D(\cos)=-\sin$$
Now let's suppose we introduce a new function, $\sin+2\cdot \cos$. What is its derivative? The linearity property tells us that, instead of having to go back to the limit definition and do a bunch of tedious calculations, we can just re-use our previous results, like this:
$$\mathrm D(\sin+2\cos)=\mathrm D(\sin)+2\mathrm D(\cos) \\ =\cos-2\sin$$
And we are done! The linearity property has saved us a lot of boring work.

Comment: i didn't understand much of the answer because it's higher level math that I know about but thanks. i understood some of it. and btw, I know this reply is years later... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have learned that the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives and that the derivative of a constant times a function is that constant times the derivative of the function.

That is what is meant by "differentiation is linear". To "apply linearity" is a fancy way to say you can use those two facts to calculate derivatives, precisely as you observe in your question. To differentiate
$$
2(x+5)
$$
all you need to know is how to differentiate $x$ and (the constant function)  $5$. Then you "apply linearity" to glue those two derivatives together.

If you go on in mathematics beyond calculus you will study *Linear Algebra* where this notion is the central concept.